# Calculating Combinations for Intra-Squad Basketball Scrimmage Teams

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

### Calculating Combinations for Intra-Squad Basketball Scrimmage Teams

I have a question regarding combinations in the context of dividing a basketball team into two equal teams for an intra-squad scrimmage. Our team consists of 10 players, which includes Steve and Danny.

I'm trying to calculate the number of ways we can form these teams under two different scenarios:

1. **Without Restrictions:** We simply divide the 10 players into two teams of 5. I calculated the answer as ${10 \choose 5}/2$, which I believe accounts for the fact that the two teams are indistinguishable (i.e., Team A vs. Team B is the same as Team B vs. Team A).
2. **Danny and Steve on the Same Team:** Here, I'm considering scenarios where Danny and Steve must be on the same team. I calculated the answer as ${8 \choose 3}$.

My confusion arises with the second scenario. Why do we not divide the answer by 2 to account for the interchangeability of the two teams, as we did in the first scenario? I would appreciate any insights or explanations on this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Essentially in (2) you have "the team with Danny and Steve" and the "team with neither of them" so ${8 \choose 3}=56$ ways of choosing the other members of the team with Danny and Steve, while in (1) you have two teams which could be either way round so ${10 \choose 5}/2=126$ ways.

There are a other ways of answering (1), including:

- Put Danny in a team and choose four other members of "Danny's team" to give ${9 \choose 4}=126$ ways
- Either have Danny and Steve in the same team with ${8 \choose 3}=56$ ways of choosing "the team with Danny and Steve" as in (2) or have Danny and Steve in different teams with ${8 \choose 4}=70$ ways of choosing the rest of "Danny's team without Steve", with a total of $56+70=126$ ways

All of these methods give consistent answers.

Answer (score 3):

The difference arises depending on whether teams are **labeled** or **unlabeled**

For unlabeled teams,ABCDE | FGHIJ is indistinguishable from FGHIJ | ABCDE

whereas if we have to have Danny and Steve on the same team, we can label it as Danny-Steve team and Other team, then every composition of the remaining three on the Danny-Steve team creates a different Danny-Steve team, so there is no division by 2

Comment: A longer explanation can be seen at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4484607/number-of-ways-to-divide-10-children-into-two-teams-of-5

Answer (score 2):

To understand why we don't want to divide by two in the latter case consider the following thought process, still using Team A and Team B.

There are two ways Danny and Steve can end up in the same team. They can both be in Team A, or both are playing in Team B. There are $\binom 83$ ways of building Team A including D & S. Similarly there are $\binom 83$ ways of building Team B including D & S. When counting this way, there are a total of $2\binom 83$ ways. Only this time we must divide by two because we don't care which way the A vs. B split goes (ok, one team might get to use the cooler looking jerseys, but we ignore that).

Comment: Thank you! This made answer was very intuitive!

Answer (score 0):

We just supposed Danny and Steve in team A, and we chose other 3 players for team A. And what we need to do is 8 choose 3 for team A, just team A.

The reason no restriction should divided by 2 is that the two team players are picked without differences.

Hope that could help you out.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

- In the first scenario you divide by 2, because `(A,B,C,D,E; F,G,H,I,J)` and `(F,G,H,I,J; A,B,C,D,E)` are equivalent and we want to avoid counting them twice.
- In the second scenario you do not divide by two, because `(Danny,Steve,A,B,C; D,E,F,G,H)` and `(Danny,Steve,D,E,F,G,H; A,B,C)` are not equivalent, and in fact the latter is not one of the considered pairings, so we don't have to worry about it.